# white-space pre-wrap not recalculating

Tags: css, internet-explorer, whitespace, word-wrap

[Fiddle illustrating the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/3ae4V/1/) - click the button a few times and the box will shrink, revealing the issue.

This issue appears to only happen in Internet Explorer.

Basically, when an element that contains `white-space: pre-wrap` is resized slowly, IE doesn't recalculate word wrapping, resulting in text being pushed outside the element. Some recalculating does happen, but not all of it. The more the element is resized, it seems, the more recalculation is actually done.

Zooming the page fixes the issue, but is obviously not a practical solution.

How can I force IE to recalculate word wrapping when the container's size changes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### New (ridiculous) HTML Change Solution (but works!)

Because of the odd first line failure, the solution depended upon generating a non-important first line and then accommodating it. [**This fiddle demonstrates**](http://jsfiddle.net/3ae4V/73/) what appears to be a now "bug free" solution for IE9 (some tweaking to account for my pseudo-element/class use would be needed for earlier IE versions).

The HTML requires an excessive amount of wrapping, such that each section of text is "double wrapped." The demo has three different means of gaining the block level wrap, but all use the same fix.

**Essential HTML**

```
<div id="cnt">
  <p class="ieFixBlockWrap">
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec tincidunt consectetur tortor, sed vestibulum lectus hendrerit at. Praesent fermentum augue molestie lectus pharetra eget cursus erat cursus.
    </span>
  </p>
  <span class="ieFixBlockWrap">
    <span>Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Praesent fringilla nisl posuere tortor rutrum lobortis.
    </span>
  </span>
  <div class="ieFixBlockWrap">
    <span>In risus libero, faucibus ac congue et, imperdiet ac purus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi aliquam lobortis ullamcorper. Proin risus sapien, pulvinar in adipiscing non, rutrum hendrerit magna. Praesent interdum pharetra vehicula. Integer molestie mi neque.
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
#cnt {
    white-space: pre-wrap; 
    border:1px solid black;
    line-height: 1.2em; /* set explicitly, see below */
    /* prevent shifted :before from interfering with elements preceeding #cnt */
    overflow: hidden; 
}

.ieFixBlockWrap:before { /* this becomes the first line, but also an extra line gap */
    content:''; 
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}

.ieFixBlockWrap { 
    display: block; /* just to demo span as block level */
    margin: -1.2em 0; /* offset by line-height to remove gaps from :before*/
}

.ieFixBlockWrap:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0; /* last one does not need the bottom margin adjusted */
}
```

### Original HTML Change Solution (still failed on first line)

Wrapping all the text in a single `span` inside the `div` set with `pre-wrap` seemed to make it behave [in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3ae4V/18/).

Comment: Excellent. This is something I can easily implement, so it's perfect. Thank you!

Comment: That said, it seems to break still when there are other block-level elements in the container, even if I wrap all individual areas with spans: http://jsfiddle.net/3ae4V/37/

Comment: @Kolink--I've noticed that it has something to do with only "consistently" reflowing if the line "above" needs to reflow. Even in my original ["solution" fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3ae4V/18/) after 15+ clicks the top line of text _fails_ and no longer wraps.

Comment: @Kolink--[Here's an easier example](http://jsfiddle.net/3ae4V/46/) to see the bizarre first line behavior. [Even if generated within the span.](http://jsfiddle.net/3ae4V/47/)

Comment: @Kolink--It seems a bit ridiculous, but I have come up with what appears to be a more "rock solid" solution to the issue to handle block level elements within.

Comment: Well, currently I only use an inline style to define an element with this `white-space:pre-wrap`, but if I use a "real" class and add the `span` tags in manually, then I can use CSS to style the block elements (since there will only be `div` and `fieldset` there). I'll give it a shot and report back later.

Comment: I've been kinda busy so I haven't been able to test this yet, but it does seem promising from the Fiddle so I'll give it the checkmark again.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can force IE to redraw the container by removing the element and then adding it back (unfortunate you have to resort to this, but oh well).  Here's a resize function that will do just that, along with [a fiddle to see it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/3ae4V/4/):

```
var resize = function(element, changeWidth, changeHeight){
    changeWidth = parseInt(changeWidth) || 0;
    changeHeight = parseInt(changeHeight) || 0;

    element.style.width = (parseInt(element.style.width) + changeWidth) + 'px';
    element.style.height = (parseInt(element.style.height) + changeHeight) + 'px';
    var parent = element.parentNode;
    parent.removeChild(element);
    parent.appendChild(element);
};
```

Comment: Okay, so that's one solution. Could be a pain to implement though since in my actual case there could be a large number of elements like this and they need to redraw when the user resizes the window.

Comment: @Kolink:  If you put them all in a single container element, you can just remove that element and put it back and it will redraw all the children.  http://jsfiddle.net/3ae4V/7/

Comment: Well, that'd pretty much reduce me to removing and re-appending the entire `body` tag, but I see what you mean.